# Unity Location service is timing out on one app, but not on the other

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, location

I am making a location-based app, that has a compass which is pointing to some Long and Lat coordinates. I need to access my own coordinates, to be able to calculate the rotation  my compass needs, but the problem is - my unity location service is timing out. This apps location sensitivity is 3 meters.

I created a second app, which is just showing you your Long and Lat coordinates with location sensitivity of 5 meters and it works almost instantly. Here is the code of my first project:

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    // First, check if user has location service enabled
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    {
        ErrorHandler.ShowMessageError("Location service not enabled");
        isLoopAllowed = false;
        yield break;
    }

    // Start service before querying location
    Input.location.Start(Storage.LOCATION_SENSITIVITY, Storage.LOCATION_SENSITIVITY);

    // Wait until service initializes
    int maxWait = 20;
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }

    // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
    if (maxWait < 1)
    {
        ErrorHandler.ShowMessageError("Timed out");
        isLoopAllowed = false;
        yield break;
    }

    // Connection has failed
    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
    {
        ErrorHandler.ShowMessageError("Can't locate your device");
        isLoopAllowed = false;
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
        //print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
        Storage.USER_LATITUDE = Input.location.lastData.latitude;
        Storage.USER_LONGITUDE = Input.location.lastData.longitude;
        Storage.LOCATION_READY = true;
    }
}
```

Some intro into the script:

isLoopKeyAllowed variable is for stopping the loop in case of an error.

Storage class is just a class with global variables.

ErrorHandler class has a function called ShowMessageError() thats just outputting the error on the screen.

LOCATION_READY is a varible that is being used by the compass script.

and thats it. I don't know whats the problem. Maybe it is caused because the sensitivity is too high?

(EDIT): The problem is, that the Timed Out error is shown and the loop has ended.

Comment: The [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html) only mentions values of `5-10` .. maybe you are right and 5 is the minimum value... Seems to be confirmed here https://forum.unity.com/threads/gps-input-location-accuracy-question.132587